# Creating an object to record a users Score

Tags: java

I am creating a quiz type console application which records the score of the user depending on the answer is correct or incorrect. I am wondering (because of multiple categories) would it be a better idea to create a score class instead of having it in the methods individually. If so, what would be the best way of implementing this. External resources also greatly welcomed

Current the code is as follows

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DummyQuiz {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int score = 0;

    public static void category1()
    {
        int answer1;
        System.out.println("Question 1");
        System.out.println("1) answer 1");
        System.out.println("2) answer 2");
        answer1 = input.nextInt();

        if(answer1 == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Correct!\n");
            score++;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect\n");
        }                     
    }//category1

    public static void main(String []args){

        category1();
        // Output final score here

    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that I am a java novice and this is simply dummy source code

Comment: If all you're storing is an int that counts the number of questions correct, it might be a bit much to write a class.  If you have multiple categories, it might be best to have the category methods return a 1/0 based on correct/incorrect and then increment the score in your main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would urge you to clean up your Question into Object(s) first. Note that the Question should be responsible for determining if the answer is correct. You create a collection (or array) of Question(s), print them (which calls toString), test for correct by calling isAnswerCorrect and I think you'll find scoring is then easy (by testing your questions collection/array size you know how many total will be asked at the start):

```
public class Question {
  private String question;
  private int answer = 1;

  public Question(String question, int answer) {
    this.question = question;
    if (answer > 0) {
      this.answer = answer;
    } else {
      System.err.println("0 is no answer (e.g. not a value)");
    }
  }

  public boolean isAnswerCorrect(Integer answer) {
    return this.answer == (int) answer;
  }

  public int getCorrectAnswer() {
    return answer;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return question;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would encapsulate values in a new class in two cases:

1. You have multiple values that belong together semantically. E.g. for first and last name your would create a person class.
2. You want to define a special behaviour for your vaules like certain mathematical operations. Then I would create a value class (which are immutable). You would do this e.g. with a money amount or a date.

In your case it's just an incrementing `int` so you should be fine, especially with such a small project. But it wouldn't be wrong to create a class anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing something like this instead:

```
public static int category1()
{
    int answer1;
    System.out.println("Question 1");
    System.out.println("1) answer 1");
    System.out.println("2) answer 2");
    answer1 = input.nextInt();

    if(answer1 == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Correct!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Incorrect\n");
        return 0;
    }                     
}//category1

public static void main(String []args){
    score += category1();
}
```

The way you are doing it now should work without an issue. You should make score a private variable so that it cannot be modified by other classes. Creating a score object would be overkill for just one primitive type.

If you want to get some practice with classes/objects, consider making a category object that holds question objects that you can call from a main class.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it a few different ways, not sure how new you are, but you probably want to use the one you feel most comfortable with

Firstly, you can use a HashMap in the same class

```
HashMap<Integer, Boolean> responses = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>(); //<K (Question #),V (Correct response)>
```

to add to this hashmap simply use

```
response.put(<question number>, <correct response?>);
```

and if you, for example wanted to print it to the console,

```
for (int i = 0; i < responses.keySet().size(); i++){
   System.out.println(responses.keySet().get(i)+" "+responses.values().get(i));
}
```

If you want to do it the alternative way and actually create a class

```
public class answers{
public List<Boolean> repsonse = new ArrayList<Boolean>();


   public void put(int num, boolean response){
numbers.set(num,response);
}
public boolean getRepsonse(int num){
return numbers.get(num)
}
}
```

but that method is really redundant

hope that helps